# getting all nodes automatically xml

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I have a problem with my javascript code where i need to get all data from a specific node. i need all the nodes 'ows_Person' to be displayed onto my site.
I can display 1 'own_person' but i need to loop thru all of them and display them all. i have no idea how im suppose to do this because i am a beginner at this kind of stuff. i would appriciate some help.

Javascript code :

```
var xmlhttp, xmlDoc;
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.xml", false);

xmlhttp.send();

xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

//Zet de XML data in een lijst.
document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("z:row")[0].getAttribute('ows_Person');

//Zet de XML data in een lijst.
document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("z:row")[0].getAttribute('ows_ID');

//Zet de XML data in een lijst.
document.getElementById("Created").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("z:row")[0].getAttribute('ows_Modified');

document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = output;
```

XML Code :

```
<xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" 
xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-
microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
<s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
<s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly" rs:CommandTimeout="30">
<s:AttributeType name="ows_Attachments" rs:name="Attachments" rs:number="1">
<s:datatype dt:type="boolean" dt:maxLength="1" />
</s:AttributeType>
<s:AttributeType name="ows_LinkTitle" rs:name="Title" rs:number="2">
<s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="512" />
</s:AttributeType>
<s:AttributeType name="ows_Person" rs:name="Person" rs:number="3">
<s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:lookup="true" dt:maxLength="512" />
</s:AttributeType>
<s:AttributeType name="ows_ID" rs:name="ID" rs:number="4">
<s:datatype dt:type="i4" dt:maxLength="4" />
</s:AttributeType>
<s:AttributeType name="ows_Modified" rs:name="Modified" rs:number="5">
<s:datatype dt:type="datetime" dt:maxLength="8" />
</s:AttributeType>
<s:AttributeType name="ows_DocIcon" rs:name="Type" rs:number="6">
<s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="512" />
</s:AttributeType>
</s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
<z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_LinkTitle="Test" ows_Person="1257;#Stefan de 
 Boer" ows_ID="1" ows_Modified="2017-11-15 15:00:22" />
 <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_LinkTitle="testtesttesttest" 
 ows_Person="1256;#Kevin" ows_ID="2" ows_Modified="2017-11-16 10:46:07" />
 <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_LinkTitle="nog een test" 
 ows_Person="1258;#Naomi" ows_ID="3" ows_Modified="2017-11-16 10:53:11" />
 <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_LinkTitle="alweer een test" 
 ows_Person="1257;#Stefan" ows_ID="4" ows_Modified="2017-11-16 10:53:44" />
 </rs:data>
 </xml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're trying to get all persons right? Try this

```
const transform = require('camaro')
const xml = `
<xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-
microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
    <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
        <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly" rs:CommandTimeout="30">
            <s:AttributeType name="ows_Attachments" rs:name="Attachments" rs:number="1">
                <s:datatype dt:type="boolean" dt:maxLength="1" />
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="ows_LinkTitle" rs:name="Title" rs:number="2">
                <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="512" />
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="ows_Person" rs:name="Person" rs:number="3">
                <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:lookup="true" dt:maxLength="512" />
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="ows_ID" rs:name="ID" rs:number="4">
                <s:datatype dt:type="i4" dt:maxLength="4" />
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="ows_Modified" rs:name="Modified" rs:number="5">
                <s:datatype dt:type="datetime" dt:maxLength="8" />
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="ows_DocIcon" rs:name="Type" rs:number="6">
                <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="512" />
            </s:AttributeType>
        </s:ElementType>
    </s:Schema>
    <rs:data>
        <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_LinkTitle="Test" ows_Person="1257;#Stefan de
 Boer" ows_ID="1" ows_Modified="2017-11-15 15:00:22" />
        <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_LinkTitle="testtesttesttest" ows_Person="1256;#Kevin" ows_ID="2" ows_Modified="2017-11-16 10:46:07" />
        <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_LinkTitle="nog een test" ows_Person="1258;#Naomi" ows_ID="3" ows_Modified="2017-11-16 10:53:11" />
        <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_LinkTitle="alweer een test" ows_Person="1257;#Stefan" ows_ID="4" ows_Modified="2017-11-16 10:53:44" />
    </rs:data>
</xml>
`

const { persons } = transform(xml, {
    persons: ['xml/rs:data/z:row', {
        ows_Person: '@ows_Person',
        ows_ID: '@ows_ID',
        ows_Modified: '@ows_Modified',
        ows_Attachments: '@ows_Attachments',
        ows_LinkTitle: '@ows_LinkTitle'
    }]
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(persons, null, 2))
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "ows_Attachments": "0",
    "ows_ID": "1",
    "ows_LinkTitle": "Test",
    "ows_Modified": "2017-11-15 15:00:22",
    "ows_Person": "1257;#Stefan de  Boer"
  },
  {
    "ows_Attachments": "0",
    "ows_ID": "2",
    "ows_LinkTitle": "testtesttesttest",
    "ows_Modified": "2017-11-16 10:46:07",
    "ows_Person": "1256;#Kevin"
  },
  {
    "ows_Attachments": "0",
    "ows_ID": "3",
    "ows_LinkTitle": "nog een test",
    "ows_Modified": "2017-11-16 10:53:11",
    "ows_Person": "1258;#Naomi"
  },
  {
    "ows_Attachments": "0",
    "ows_ID": "4",
    "ows_LinkTitle": "alweer een test",
    "ows_Modified": "2017-11-16 10:53:44",
    "ows_Person": "1257;#Stefan"
  }
]
```